# how do I test (rspec) a http request that takes too long?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd

How do I test the behavior if a request takes too long with rspec?

I am thinking of using thread to mock this:

```
describe "Test" do 
  it "should timeout if the request takes too long" do 
    lambda {
      thread1 = Thread.new { #net::http request to google.com }
      thread2 = Thread.new { sleep(xx seconds) }
      thread1.join 
      thread2.join
    }.should raise_error
  end 
end
```

I want to make sure that after the request is first made, another thread "kicks in" which in this case is just a sleep for xx seconds. Then I should expect the request to timeout because it takes too long to execute

I think that there are better ways to do this. Given the fact that the url I am requesting is not relevant. I just want to test that it will indeed timeout if it takes too long to execute.

Can I use stub(), expect() or any rspec features to simulate this?

Is there any way that I can pass in a 'block' into stub method

```
http_request_to_google.stub(:connection).executethisblock(sleep for xx seconds)
.and_throw error ?
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you purely care about Net::HTTP raising a Timeout::Error, you could always just force it to return the error with a mock, [here](https://gist.github.com/663876) is a good compilation of various things you can use with RSpec.

It would depend on your exact Net::HTTP request, but something such as `Net::HTTP.should_receive(:request_get).and_raise(Timeout::Error)` would skip any networking calls and just raise the error immediately.

Comment: right. the networking call itself is not important. so "forcing it to return error with a mock" would imply that the test will fail when it executes too long (or reached timeout) ?

Comment: It's slightly confusing what you're asking for from your phrasing. Are you trying to ensure that your test doesn't take longer than X seconds to run. Or are you trying to test what happens theoretically if your network call took too long to run? If you're trying to test the latter, then the example I gave will do that for you.

Comment: I am trying to test the latter. Oh I guess I need to read more about Rspec::Mocks. Thanks!

Comment: Yea what I gave you will work then. The only thing to keep in mind, is there are different types of timeouts. There's `Timeout::Error` and `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`, in your case, you probably want to raise the former to test it. But if you have problems, try the latter as well.

Comment: How you call the mock exactly will vary based on your actual HTTP call as well, if you're using a POST you naturally can't raise on `request_get` and so on.

Comment: is request_get part of net http? I actually have not coded this at all. I am just thinking how this can be done. 

So I can do this:
myobject.should_receive(:method that requests to a certain     url).and_raise(Timeout::Error)

Basically I use Rspec's 'should_receive' and 'and_raise' to mock this behavior theoretically without caring the actual network calls. Correct?

Comment: It is. What method you call depends on how you structure it and what data you want out of it though. You would have to look around for examples. You are correct about wanting to use `should_receive` as well as `and_raise` to mock it though.

Comment: thanks..Can I pass in a block instead of method to should_receive? I think I can

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7052/discussion-between-zachary-anker-and-limanoit)

Answer (score 11):

The below test fails if request doesn't finish in 20 seconds. It also fails if the code in the lambda doesn't raise Timeout::Error.

So, successful scenario is when long_running_stuff raises exception in less than 20 seconds.

```
require 'timeout'

describe "Test" do 
  it "should timeout if the request takes too long" do 
    Timeout::timeout(20) do # 20 seconds
      lambda {
         long_running_stuff(:timeout => 10.seconds)
      }.should raise_error(Timeout::Error)
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. should definitely try that. Hmmm any solution that does not introduce a new gem.. thanks tho

Comment: `timeout` is built-in to ruby. You don't need introduce a new gem, you get it for free.

Comment: seems like it will work! the only thing it will make the test runs longer? haha

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is ancient, but here's another solution using the [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#raising-timeout-errors) gem:

```
stub_request(:any, 'www.google.com').to_timeout
```

Another nice benefit to stubbing the request with Webmock is that this will continue to work even if you swap out your HTTP client, which decouples your tests from your code.

Comment: That is great anyway. Thanks.