# How to simulate Request Timeout in rspec with faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, faraday

I use Faraday gem in app, and I want to test how my app works when Faraday connection fails by timeout. How can I stub request for this case?

Comment: `allow(conn).to receive(:get).and_raise(Faraday::TimeoutError)` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008442/how-do-i-test-rspec-a-http-request-that-takes-too-long

Comment: thanks, I've seen it, but my app catches this error, and works with it. It cannon raise exception, I want to test how it works.

Comment: Maybe setup a firewall rule that will drop packets (silently discard them) to the destination host. I think that'll cause Faraday connection to that host to timeout.

Comment: You could use webmock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552239/webmock-simulate-failing-api-no-internet-timeout

Comment: But I'm a bit confused; if you application swallows the error how do you actually expect to test different outcomes?

Comment: @maxcal: ```rescue Faraday::ClientError => e``` and write fail_reason to db as e.code

Answer (score 2):

I found a working method. May be it is not beautiful, but is works.

```
faraday_adapter.post('fail') do
  raise Faraday::TimeoutError
end
```